# AS3: memory leak with two loaders

Tags: actionscript-3, loader

I have a AS3 file with only one frame. Here is the code :

```
stop();
trace("Debut du code.");
var chargeur:Loader = new Loader();
var chargeur2:Loader = new Loader();
var adress:URLRequest = new URLRequest("img/idle.swf");

chargeur.load(adress);
addChild(chargeur);

chargeur.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,isLoaded)

function isLoaded (evt:Event) {
trace("Loading complete");
var adress2:URLRequest = new URLRequest("img/oldcoucou.swf");

chargeur2.load(adress2);
addChild(chargeur2);
}
```

Problem is : there is a memory leak , something like 3mo/s... and I can't figure why and what I'm doing wrong. Any clues ?

Thanks.

Edit:
With only one loader, I don't have the memory leak. If I load two, then hide one (chargeur.visible=false or chargeur.y=1200), no memory leak either. The problem occurs only when there is 2 visible at the same time. That sounds crazy, I know... I was hoping it was a know bug or a mistake in the code...

Comment: Presumably the memory link is in the SWF's you are loading.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the loaded .swf's don't include any memory leaks the following code should be leak free.

```
stop();
trace("Debut du code.");
var chargeur:Loader = new Loader();
var chargeur2:Loader = new Loader();
var adress:URLRequest = new URLRequest("img/idle.swf");
var adress2:URLRequest = new URLRequest("img/oldcoucou.swf");

chargeur.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,isLoaded, false, 0, true);
chargeur.load(adress);

function isLoaded (evt:Event):void {

chargeur.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,isLoaded);
adress = null;
trace("Loading1 complete");
addChild(chargeur);

chargeur2.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,isLoaded2, false, 0, true);
chargeur2.load(adress2);

}

function isLoaded2 (evt:Event):void {

chargeur2.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,isLoaded2);
adress2 = null;
trace("Loading2 complete");
addChild(chargeur2);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Same problem still. That must come from the swf then... but I don't see any leak when I run them directly. Also, with only one loader, I don't have the memory leak. If I load two, then hide one (chargeur.visible=false or chargeur.y=1200), no memory leak either. The problem occurs only when there is 2 visible at the same time. That sounds crazy, I know... I was hoping it was a know bug or my code was somehow wrong...

Comment: How are you identifying the memory leak?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is impossible.
I guess the swf one be loaded into your program, it immediately run itself's program, it were that
it load other swf , swf A load swf B, swf B load swf A ....... \n. it's like a endless recusion function causing the stack overflow.